# How to write an ESC charcter in a string in R?

Tags: r

http://math.oxford.emory.edu/site/math117/stringsInR/

I see that `\n` is OK. But `\e` is not OK. How to write an ESC character in a string?

```
R> cat('\n')

R> cat('\e')
Error: '\e' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "'\e"
```

Comment: Try with `cat("\\e")`

Comment: an_esc <- cat('\\e')
\e> an_esc
NULL, is this expected>

Comment: The proper place to look for this information if you are at an R console is on the `?Quotes` page

Comment: @user1424739  Were you trying to construct a ctrl-e character? If so you were asking the wrong question. Putting an escape character before a letter only works for a few of the ctrl-characters. Try "\005"

Comment: @Chris The effect of sending esc-e to the console will depend on how it handles escape sequences. If you do it at an Rstudio console you just get `\e` on one line and the prompt on the next, but at a Linux Terminal console the behavior is as you described. I don't think the console behavior would be considered "expected"  but it's probably "undefined". The NULL value being assigned would be "expected" since that result is described on the help page I cited.

Answer (score 5):

The escape key in ASCII is 27 which is `0x1B` in hexadecimal or `033` in octal. The easiest way to get this in R is by typing `"\033"`:

```
esc <- "Esc\033ape"

esc
#> [1] "Esc\033ape"

cat("Esc\033ape")
#> Escpe
```

Note that in a string in R, this simply has the effect of removing the subsequent character from the printed output. You can see that above, and see it even more clearly if we do:

```r
cat(paste(letters, collapse = ''))
#> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

cat(paste(letters, collapse = '\033'))
#> a
```

Comment: Any other expected uses, which I suppose I should be asking @user1424739, as in the collapse context it looks both expected and side effect. All my attempts place result `inside>` my prompt.

Comment: The result of `paste(letters, collapse = '\033')` is not the single letter "a" but is rather a mixture of letters and escape-chars. If you do `print" on it you will see this.

Comment: Noted. `paste`ing demonstrates without cat, and places output outside > prompt. Other bash shell side effects, side scroll incapacitated as to prior history, but arrow keys still navigate. `paste(c('\033', letters), collapse='\033')`, interesting. Oddly similar to `invisible`.